# Getting An Error When Yii Tries To Read The User Role

Tags: php, web, yii, role, rbac

I'am a new in Yii and I'm trying to do a RBAC control in my web application. I write an authorization and registration pages and everything working perfect. But when I trying to read current user's role using Yii::app()->user->role I'm getting an error with the following content:

```
PHP warning
include(User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I did everything like in official cookbook. Honestly, I don't know why this happens that's why if someone could help me to solve this problem I will be very appreciated.

Here I wrote the steps which I did when writing the role based user control.
As mentioned in official Yii cookbook I created a simple database table named users where I defined the role attribute. Then I write a WebUser class:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    private $_model = null;

    function getRole() {
        if($user = $this->getModel()){
            return $user->role;
        }
    }

    private function getModel(){
        if (!$this->isGuest && $this->_model === null){
            $this->_model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id, array('select' => 'role'));
        }
        return $this->_model;
    }
}
```

Next step I changed the default realization of the UserIdentity::authentificate() method, where I trying to assign role to the current user:

```
public function authenticate()
    {
        $users = Users::model()->find('LOWER(name)=?', array(strtolower($this->name)));
        if($users === null)
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if ($users->validatePassword(md5($this->password))) 
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;

        else
        {
            $this->_id = $users->id;
            $this->username = $users->name;

            $auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

            echo "user role = ".$users->role.", user id = ".$this->_id;
            if(!$auth->isAssigned($users->role,$this->_id))
            {
                if($auth->assign($users->role,$this->_id))
                {
                    Yii::app()->authManager->save();
                }
            }

            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return $this->errorCode == self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
```

...
Finally, I declare all this components in the main web config file:

```
...
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),
...

'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'class'=>'WebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        'authManager' => array(
            'class' => 'PhpAuthManager',
            'defaultRoles' => array('guest'),
        ),
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In getModel() you're using `User::model()`, but in authenticate() you're calling `Users::model()`, could it be that you're trying to call the wrong model class (it's Users instead of User)?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I made a mistake in WebUser::getModel() method. I should call my model Users (in pluralize form).